# React program works fine on jscomplete.com/repl but the same code gives me the following error when I run in my browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

React program works fine on jscomplete.com/repl but the same code gives me the following error when I run in my browser, writing my code in my editor and using babel.

```
babel-browser.min.js:41 Uncaught SyntaxError: http://localhost/react1/app.jsx: Unexpected token (2:14)
  1 | class Button extends React.Component{
> 2 |   handleClick = () => {
    |               ^
  3 |     this.props.onClickFunction(this.props.incrementValue);
  4 |   }
  5 |   render() {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handleClick` function in that code is defined as a class instance field which is not yet part of JS (currently at stage 2)

To make it work, you have to configure Babel with one plugin that includes it (for example, `babel-preset-stage-2`, or directly `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`).

Alternatively, use a normal function definition in the class and bind it to `this` inside the constructor of the component.